# Matrix multiplication in Numpy takes too much time

Tags: numpy

I am trying to simply implement a loss function (MSE) in Python using numpy and this is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def loss(X, y, w):
    N = (X.shape)[0]
    X_new = np.concatenate((np.ones((N, 1)), X), axis=1)
    E = y-np.matmul(X_new, w)
    E_t = np.transpose(E)
    loss_value = (1/N)*(np.matmul(E_t, E))
    return loss_value
```

The dimension of `E` is (15000, 1) and `E_t` is obviously (1,15000). However, when debugging, I realized that `np.matmul(E_t,E)` takes too much time. I have a laptop with 16GB of RAM and Core i7, so it's weird for me that `np.matmul` is failing here. Is this normal if the matrices I am dealing with have these dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

On a rather basic 4GB machine:

```
In [477]: E=np.ones((15000, 1))                                                                        
In [478]: E.T@E                                                                                        
Out[478]: array([[15000.]])
In [479]: timeit E.T@E                                                                                 
10.5 µs ± 241 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

You don't tell us anything about `X`, but assuming the worse case:

```
In [480]: E=np.ones((15000, 1),object)                                                                 
In [481]: E.T@E                                                                                        
Out[481]: array([[15000]], dtype=object)
In [482]: timeit E.T@E                                                                                 
577 µs ± 492 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: X is `(15000, 10)` so `X_new` is `(15000, 11)`. But still the first `np.matmul` is multiplying `X_new` with `w` which is `(11, 1)` and it is not slow. I am really baffled by this, I really don't know why it takes too much time for the second `np.matmul`...